# I removed the bottom bar of VScode which shows the errors and errors, how can I recover it؟

Tags: visual-studio-code

I made an error yesterday when I was editing for a web contest, but no matter how hard I tried to send those edits to GitHub, I had to try the options in VS as usual to solve various problems. But I pressed an option without thinking and the E light disappears in the image below. Now I do not know how to return it.

[image]

And now my VS is like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open Settings using the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>
2. Search for "Workbench Status Bar" and look for the following option
   [image: settings option]
3. Tick this checkbox